# The limit of $\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_0+a_1+a_2+.......a_n$ where $a_p=\sum_{i=0}^p (-1)^i\frac{\binom{p}{i}}{(i+2)(i+4)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

I have taken this question from molodovian national MO 2008
The question is as follows

The sequence $(a_p)_p\ge 0$ is defined as  $$a_p=\sum_{i=0}^p (-1)^i\frac{\binom{p}{i}}{(i+2)(i+4)}$$

Now let's find the limit

\begin{align*} \lim_{n \to +\infty} a_0+a_1+a_2+.......a_n \end{align*}

[image]

Can anyone help me to go further.

Comment: Using the binomial theorem, you can see that $a_p=0$. Is there a typo?

Comment: I'm so sorry  , There is a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$\begin{split}
S_{k,p} &= \sum_{i=0}^p\binom{p}{i}\frac{(-1)^i}{i+k}\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^p\binom{p}{i}(-1)^i\int_0^1 x^{i+k-1}dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \sum_{i=0}^p\binom{p}{i}(-1)^ix^{i+k-1}dx\\
&= \int_0^1 x^{k-1}(1-x)^pdx
\end{split}$$
Then since $$\frac 1{(i+2)(i+4)}=\frac 1 2 \left(\frac 1 {i+2}-\frac 1 {i+4}\right)$$
we have
$$a_p=\frac 1 2 (S_{2,p}-S_{4,p})=\frac 1 2 \int_0^1 (x-x^3)(1-x)^pdx$$
Thus,

$$\begin{split}
\sum_{p=0}^n &a_p= \frac 1 2 \int_0^1(x-x^3)\sum_{p=0}^n(1-x)^pdx\\
&=\frac 1 2 \int_0^1(x-x^3)\frac{1-(1-x)^{n+1}}{x}dx\\
&=\frac 1 2 \int_0^1 (1-x^2)(1-(1-x)^{n+1})dx\\
\end{split}$$

Using [Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem):
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\sum_{p=0}^n a_p = \frac 1 2 \int_0^1 (1-x^2)dx=\frac 1 2 \left (1- \frac 1 3\right) = \frac 1 {3}$$

Comment: I think that we disagree.

Comment: I had a mistake. Do we agree now?

Comment: Now, we do ! Cheers :-)

Comment: There is a very simple expression for the partial sum if you identify what is $a_p$ (very simple).

Comment: I'm intrigued. Please post a solution!

Comment: I do not have time but do it and add in your good answer as another apporach. Show first that $a_p=\frac{p+6}{2 (p+2) (p+3) (p+4)}$ and then that the summation from $0$ to $n$ is $\frac{2 n^2+11 n+9}{6 (n+3) (n+4)}$. This will be your homework for today. Cheers :-)

Comment: Elegant solution (+1). @Claud Leibovici, it would be interesting to see your approach :)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, I am unable to understand your solution approach. I am also interested to see your approach.

Comment: @Stefen Lafon, Your solution is very elegant. Can you please explain to me how $\lim_{n \to +\infty} 1-(1-x)^{n+1}=1$. I don't know much about the dominated convergence theorem so I'm asking this question.

Comment: Sure! First, you can verify that for all $x\neq 0$, we have $0\leq 1-x<1$ thus taking increasing powers makes it converge to $0$. The DCT theorem allows you to take the limit pointwise inside the integral. First, the integrand $(1-x^2)(1-(1-x)^{n+1})\rightarrow 1-x^2$ almost everywhere, since the limit is true for all $x\neq 0$. Second the integrand is dominated (upper bounded) by $(1-x^2)$, whose integral is finite. By Lebesgue's theorem, the limit of the integral is the integral of the pointwise limit.

Comment: Thanks, @Stefen Lafon.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of Stefan Lafon is elegant and shows the usefulness of professional tools. Integral representations (or, moreover, the dominated convergence theorem) are probably not the intended solution of an MO problem, though. So it may be interesting to see how to derive explicit expressions for $a_p$ and the partial sums without any calculus.

This can be done with finite differences (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference):
If we define $\Delta_h[f](x)=f(x+h)-f(x)$, the formula for $n$th order forward differences will be
$$\Delta^n_h[f](x)=\sum^n_{i=0}\,(-1)^{n-i}\binom{n}{i}f(x+i\,h),$$ or for the special case of stepsize $h=1$,
$$\Delta^n[f](x)=\sum^n_{i=0}\,(-1)^{n-i}\binom{n}{i}f(x+i).$$ This means that
$$a_p=(-1)^p\Delta^n[f](0),\tag1$$
where $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac1{(x+2)(x+4)}$. Now it's easy to calculate forward differences for $\displaystyle f_a(x)=\frac1{x+a}$:
$$\Delta[f_a](x)=\frac1{x+a+1}-\frac1{x+a}=\frac{-1}{(x+a)(x+a+1)},$$
$$\Delta^2[f_a](x)=\frac{-1}{(x+a+1)(x+a+2)}-\frac{-1}{(x+a)(x+a+1)}=\frac{(-1)(-2)}{(x+a)(x+a+1)(x+a+2)},$$ and by induction
$$\Delta^p[f_a](x)=\frac{(-1)^p\,p!}{(x+a)\ldots(x+a+p)}.$$ For a positive integer $a$, this gives $$\Delta^p[f_a](0)=\frac{(-1)^p\,(a-1)!\,p!}{(p+a)!}=(-1)^p\,\frac{(a-1)!}{(p+1)\ldots(p+a)}.\tag2$$
Since $$f(x)=\frac1{(x+2)(x+4)}=\frac12\,\left(f_2(x)-f_4(x)\right),$$ combining (1) and (2) yields
$$a_p=\frac12\,\left(\frac{1!}{(p+1)(p+2)}-\frac{3!}{(p+1)(p+2)(p+3)(p+4)}\right)=\frac{p+6}{2\,(p+2)(p+3)(p+4)},\tag3$$ as announced in a comment. Of course, it would be possible to obtain (3) from the integral representation as well, substituting $x\to 1-y$. The partial sums $\displaystyle\sum^n_{p=0}a_p$ can be computed as telescoping sums, using $$\frac1{(p+1)(p+2)}=\frac1{p+1}-\frac1{p+2}$$ and
$$\frac1{(p+1)(p+2)(p+3)(p+4)}=\frac13\left(\frac1{(p+1)(p+2)(p+3)}-\frac1{(p+2)(p+3)(p+4)}\right).$$
So,
$$\sum^n_{p=0}a_p=\frac12\left(1-\frac1{n+2}\right)-\frac16+\frac1{(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}=\frac{2n^2+11n+9}{6\,(n+3)(n+4)}.$$

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Was that what you had in mind?

Comment: Thanks for this solution (+1).

Comment: @Stefan Lafon I'm glad you like it. There are other solutions without calculus, naturally, but they are less.... erm... pretty.

Comment: I personally have soft spot for solutions based on integral representations :-)

Comment: @Stefan Lafon So do I. They are very flexible, though it may be a challenge to find the correct one. But I happen to come from MO, where calculus was discouraged (because not all students knew it), so we had to find other ways. Of course, that was very long ago (seventies).